# VS Code Ctrl+Click removes quotes surrounding URL fragments

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

If there is a link in VS Code editor that is like `https://example.com?q=%22hello%22`, when you Ctrl+Click on that the browser receives the URL with the surrounding quotes (`%22`) removed like so: `https://example.com/?q=hello`. How to make sure the quotes aren't removed?

Comment: The url is unchanged for me: Windows 10, Edge.  https://example.com/?q=%22hello%22  I don't think there is any vscode setting that affects this.  Some other part of your system.

Comment: I used Chrome browser. I will try this with Edge and check.

Comment: Tested with Edge, works perfectly. I am able to repro this with Chrome on Windows 10. Should be Chrome issue then?